# How to passing parameter on JSP to servlet without link or do clicked

Tags: jsp, servlets, scriptlet

I had problem to refresh my list, I will do send parameter to servlet

when I do with hyperlink I will do like this.

```
<a href="ServletTransaksi?action=refresh">Refresh table</a>
```

I use scriptlet. How can I refresh my list without clicked something.

thanks

Comment: You can use ajax to update your list whenever you want.

Comment: I dont use jquery at that script

Comment: So if you don't want to use AJAX, you can try to refresh the page manually using javascript. I mean using javascript you can try to redirect the user to the same page to update te table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript, and bind an AJAX request to any page. For example, when the page loads, you can add the code.

**Example**

```
document.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                // Your request has gone through.
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ServletTransaksi?action=refresh", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}, false);
```

On page load, this will make a request to the server and refresh the table. You can add code where i've commented saying `// Your request has gone through`.

***NOTE***: This code does not use *any* jQuery, and is written in completely original Javascript. I've never understood the logic in pulling down the whole jQuery toolkit, if you're only going to be making AJAX requests with it.

**Extra Reading**

- Firstly, read up on AJAX so you know what is going on. You can read here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14142/AJAX-Explained
- Secondly, I would look into the different types of events you can bind with Javascript. These are available here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

Comment: xmlhttp.status is a session for counting page on load?

Comment: No, the status is the status of the request. `200` means it went fine. `404` means file not found, `403` is permission denied, etc.